# get ip address of a website with J2ME

Tags: java-me, ip-address

I want to get IP address of website e.g., **http://www.sssssss.vvv** has IP address **111.22.3.4**.

With Java SE we can get as below.

```
String ipAddrs = InetAddress.getByName("http://www.sssssss.vvv").getHostAddress();
```

Can anybody please tell me to get same thing with **J2ME API.**

I searched online for solution to this question, but no use.